# @discordjs/voice Engine Unsuported

Tags: discord.js

Hello I am facing a problem with @discordjs/voice.
It says Unsuported Engine. but i have node version v17.6.0

here are the photos:[image]

[image]

Answer (score -1):

As the error mentions in plain English your version if nodejs is older than the required version. I suggest you reinstall from [here](https://nodejs.org/en/download/current/) or any version above 16.9.0 or equal to ir